# Detect IPC between running processes on Unix

Tags: unix, pipe, hook

Suppose I have 2 processes on any unix-based system and I sure they are using some inter-process communication. How can I detect what do they use in order to simulate or hook it? I mean `pipes`, for example, or any else IPC method.

P.S. Not for bad goals :)

P.P.S. Any solution is appreciated: coding a program, using existing tool, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the method of IPC, there are a lot of them.
If sockets are used, you can may be intersept / track the comunication with appropriate tool like WireShark or something else.

But consider the communication over shared memory / file.
A one process writes to some file, the another one reads and vice versa: how do you want to intersept such a IPC?

Take a look at [this Wiki site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to see the main methods provided by UNIX / POSIX systems.

Comment: So no any tool can be used specifically for that? I know about wireshark and I've read this wiki article. I was asking about special software or universal methods.

Comment: IMHO there is not any universal tool because of different methods of communication as I've wrote.